# Having difficulty in creating a Pie Chart using the 'plotly' module

Tags: python, plotly, pie-chart

I want to create/draw a PieChart on the coordinate plane. I was able to write the following code:

```
import copy
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import plotly.graph_objs as go


def plot_pie_instead_of_a_marker(fig, x_points, y_points, pie_data, colors, sign, title, unit='',
                                 text=None, norm_param=1, max_r=None, radius_by_par=None):
    def degree2rad(degrees):
        return degrees * np.pi / 180

    def disk_part(center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, koef, n_points=50):
        t = np.linspace(degree2rad(start_angle), degree2rad(end_angle), n_points)
        x = center[0] + radius * np.cos(t)
        y = center[1] + radius * koef * np.sin(t)
        return np.append(x, (center[0], x[0])), np.append(y, (center[1], y[0]))

    data = [[pie[i] for pie in pie_data] for i in range(0, len(x_points))]

    if max_r is None:
        max_r = 0.05
    if radius_by_par is None:
        radius = np.full(len(x_points), max_r)
    else:
        radius = [max_r * i + 0.02 for i in radius_by_par / max(radius_by_par)]
    sign_catalog = []

    if text is not None:
        sign = f'ID' + ': {0}<br>' + sign
        for title_name in title:
            s = copy.deepcopy(sign)
            s = s + f'<br>{title_name}' + ': {3} ' + unit
            sign_catalog.append(s)
    koef = max(x_points) / max(y_points)
    for x, y, (a, b), id, r in zip(x_points, y_points, data, text, radius):
        ratio = a / (a + b)
        for start_angle, end_angle, color, sign in zip(
                (0, 360 * ratio), (360 * ratio, 359.9), colors, sign_catalog
        ):
            if start_angle == 0:
                name = sign.format(id, x, y, round(a * norm_param, 0))
            else:
                name = sign.format(id, x, y, round(b * norm_param, 0))
            x_disk, y_disk = disk_part([x, y], r, start_angle, end_angle, koef)
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=x_disk,
                    y=y_disk,
                    mode='lines',
                    fill="toself",
                    fillcolor=color,
                    line={"color": color},
                    name=name,
                    showlegend=False,
                    hoverinfo='text',
                    hovertext=name,
                    hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor="white", font_color="black")
                )
            )

    fig.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1)


fig = go.Figure()
max_x = 1
x = np.array([0.19, 0.3, 0.81, 0.84])
y = np.array([130, 60, 50, 85])
max_y = max(y)
pie_qo = np.array([98, 75, 95, 80])
pie_qw = np.array([2, 25, 5, 20])
text = np.array(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
plot_pie_instead_of_a_marker(
    fig,
    x[y > 0],
    y[y > 0] * (max_x / max_y),
    pie_data=[
        pie_qo[y > 0],
        pie_qw[y > 0]
    ],
    colors=['green', 'deepskyblue'],
    sign="x val: {1: .2f} <br>y val: {2:.2f} ",
    title=['Pie 1', 'Pie 2'],
    unit='some_unit',
    text=text[y > 0],
    norm_param=(max_x / max_y),
)
y_tick = np.array([round(0.2 * i * max_y, 0) for i in range(0, int((max_x + 0.2) / 0.2))])
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_range=[0, 1 + 0.1],
    yaxis_tickvals=y_tick / max_y,
    yaxis_ticktext=y_tick,
    xaxis_range=[0, max_x + 0.4]
)
fig.show()
```

But, there are a few problems:

Here is the image of the problem occuring - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dux5U.png

1. On the x axis, the zoom is not starting from 0.
2. The zoom is not working well.

How do I solve the problem if the values in the range x and y are [0, 1.2] and [140, 250]?